# selecting substring upto the specific character in db2 sql

Tags: sql, db2

I need to get three substrings from the single string.
For eample, if the string is abc-def-ghi, i need to select abc as 1 column and def as 2nd column and ghi as 3rd column.

Comment: what will be the length for the total string & also for the substring

Comment: total length was 30 and each substring has a different length. I need to select based on the character '-' in the string

Comment: Okay, It means you need to split by '-' to three caharacters. Please give the example how word will look like

Comment: The word will look like abcddfef-ghijklfgll-mhfagsjjgk

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [posstr](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000835.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-9-4-1-119&lang=en) function to locate a character in a string, and then use the [substr](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000854.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-9-4-1-150&lang=en) function to retrieve a part from a string. This could be done from an anonymous block or stored procedure.

You put this in a function (UDF):

```
set index = posstr(string, '-');
if (index <> 0) then -- Recursive case
 set pre = substr(string, index-1);
 set pos = substr(string, index+1);
else -- Base case
 set pre = substr(string, index-1);
end if;
```

Depending on the logic, you can insert these values in a temporary table and return a result set.

Comment: From this i can find the first occurance of the character but i need to identify the next occurances too.

Comment: The you do a recursion. Or a substr from the second part

Comment: How to do the recursion of posstr.

Comment: @AngocA db2 sql & sql are two different database?

Comment: I updated my answer. You can see an example here: https://github.com/angoca/log4db2/blob/master/src/main/sql-pl/GET_LOGGER.sql

Comment: @Anbuvictor SQL is almost standard in all database. Many of them follow the SQL-92 standard. However, procedural language is not standard across DBs. DB2 almost follows ANSI procedural language, as Postgres does. The others RDBS do not follow any standard. That is the reason your previous (deleted) answer is only valid for SQL server, because it not only uses SQL but also T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Locate command along with substr to split the string into two or more substrings based